# magento load product by id with limit thing

Tags: magento-1.9, product

i wrote a code to get product list by id below is my code :

```
$category_id = $_GET['category_id']; 
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','name','url','small_image','price')); //add product attribute to be fetched

$collection->addStoreFilter();          

if(!empty($collection)){
    foreach ($collection as $_product){
        $categoryapi['id']=$_product->getId();
        $categoryapi['name']=$_product->getName();
        $categoryapi['price']=$_product->getPrice();
        $categoryapi['image']=(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(250, 250);
        $mcat[] = $categoryapi;
    }
}
echo $output = json_encode(array('data' => $mcat));
```

my code works fine but i want to add limit so it loads products in count of 10 like for first request 1,10 and then 11,20 and then 21,30 and so on .

how can it be done please guide way to do it

Comment: add the code ->setPageSize($per_page) for how many products want to show in a page to collection. $per_page is the number of product.

Comment: how can i pass paramter like page ?

Comment: Can you get the limited value from -setPageSize()?
That you want to pass the value with the pagination link and catch the parameter for $per_page.

Comment: thanks for same also one thing i set ">addAttributeToSelect(array('id','name','url','small_image','price'));"

but still when i print array is show fields like "attribute_set_id",type_id,sku ,created at why so ?

Comment: You can give ->addAttributeToSelect('*') for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `->setPageSize($per_page)` to your collection to add limit.

```
$category_id = $_GET['category_id']; 
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','name','url','small_image','price')); //add product attribute to be fetched
$collection->setPageSize($per_page);
$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

You can pass the value for `$per_page`by your pagination.
**Hope this will help you to get the limit.**

Comment: can u tell what to do to make addAttributeToSelect as i do not want unnecessary value that might slow up code run time

Comment: Did you try addFieldToSelect() instead of addAttributeToSelect()?

Comment: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addFieldToSelect()

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value